# System-Level Custom Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to do the following in SQL Server (2008 + ):

1. Define a view, let's call it `[MySchema].[MyTableInfo]`, that queries the SQL Server catalog views, e.g., `[sys].[tables]`, to obtain a customized presentation of the underlying catalog metadata.
2. Install this view somewhere (in `master`?) so that it can be called from the context of any database on the server and return the metadata appropriate for that context, just as the catalog views do.

I have seen reference to techniques to do something similar with utility stored procedures, but this is a little different. Is what I'm wanting to do possible? If so, how?

**Update**:
I found an [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1612/creating-your-own-sql-server-system-stored-procedures) that described how to do almost exactly what I want but with stored procedures. The routines are stored in the master database and marked as system objects. When they return metadata from the catalog views/information schema, the do so in the context of the current database.

Using stored procedures to execute these queries would be extremely inconvenient for my use case; is there not a way to mark views and/or table-valued functions as system objects and have them execute in the context of the calling database? I have hacked on this without success...

Comment: You want to create a view of sys.tables on Master, and query it from another database to see results for that database??

Comment: I want to create custom metadata views that can be accessed from any database on the server so, yes, the result of the view would vary depending on what database it was accessed from, just like sys.tables or any other catalog view